# Compute shader lock an object so that it can't be processed by more than one thread

Tags: synchronization, gpu, compute-shader

I'm new to compute shaders, is there any way to lock an object once a thread is processing it in a way that no other thread can simultaneously process it until it's "unlocked"?

I'm trying to synchronize it but I don't know how